# Hive query - INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY creates multiple files for a single table

Tags: hive

I do the following from a hive table myTable.

INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/myDir/out' SELECT concat_ws('',NAME,PRODUCT,PRC,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) FROM myTable;

So, this command generates 2 files 000000_0 and 000001_0 inside the folder out/.

But, I need the contents as a single file. What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple files in the directory because every reducer is writing one file. If you really need the contents as a single file, run your map reduce job with only **1 reducer** which will write to a single file.

However depending on your data size, this might not be a good approach to run a single reducer.

Edit: Instead of forcing hive to run 1 reduce task and output a single reduce file, it would be better to use hadoop fs operations to merge outputs to a single file.
For example

```
hadoop fs -text /myDir/out/* | hadoop fs -put - /myDir/out.txt
```

Comment: when I run this.. It shows 0 reducers. As : Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator..

Comment: so in this case the output of all mappers is directly written to HDFS since there is no reduce operator. Try setting the number of mappers to 1 and see what happens

Comment: Do I need to set mapred.map.tasks=1 ?

Comment: yes the syntax seems correct.....but what happens is that hadoop internally only takes a hint about the number of map reduce task and doesn't force it...you can only freely tune the number of reduce tasks and not the map tasks....try setting it to one and see if works

Comment: set mapred.map.tasks=1; then ran my query. ==> Again 2 files. Log is:Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_2014123423520_1324, Tracking URL = http://.............com:52330/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_2014122212340_1324
Kill Command = /opt/cloudera.....................
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 2; number of reducers: 0
2015-02-02 02:24:06,047 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-02-02 02:24:16,189 Stage-1 map = 50%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 8.84 sec

Comment: thats what...the number of map tasks cannot be forced and depends on the split size....if you really want to have a single file instead of two try adding a reduce job to your query which doesn't really impact your output ...

Comment: ok before that, could you please tell me why really you need a single file ?....it might be the case that there is a better alternative

Comment: I need to have a single output file after all the processings and need to send that single file to the next process. I can do a cat -> linux command or need to append using java. Instead of these, I thought of making it a single file using hive itseif.

Comment: modified the answer, please check

Comment: Could u pl ans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404306/getting-unordered-output-while-using-hive-order-by-query

Answer (score 6):

A bit late to the game, but I found that using `LIMIT large_number`, where `large_number` is bigger than rows in your query. It forces hive to use at least a reducer. For example:

`set mapred.reduce.tasks=1; INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/myDir/out' SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1000000000`

Worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

CLUSTER BY will make the work.

Comment: please add some more detail about CLUSTER BY